# Dividing rational expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

**Just to clarify, I do not want anyone to do the problem for me.  I just need someone to explain this stuff to me because I'm completely lost, and I would really appreciate it if you could take the time to do so.**

In the book I've been reading they have this example:

$$\frac{y^3-1}{y^2-1} \div \frac{y^2 + y + 1}{y^2 + 2y + 1}$$

So I understand the basic concept: you flip the fraction so that you're multiplying, then factor everything on top and everything on the bottom, then you cancel things that are the same on top and on the bottom. What I don't understand is, when they factor the numerator, they get rid of a "2" and I'm not really sure how they did that:

$$\frac{y^3 - 1}{y^2 - 1} \div \frac{y^2 + 2y + 1}{y^2 + y + 1}$$

**Factor:**

$$(y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + y + 1) \div (y + 1)(y - 1)(y^2 + y + 1)$$

**Cancel things out:**

$$y + 1$$

So the problem I have is that they have $(y^3 - 1)(y^2 + 2y + 1)$ on top, but somehow they factor it out to: $(y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + y + 1)$; how is that possible? I get that $(y^3 - 1)$ factors out to:

$$(y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)$$

but how did they get rid of the "2" in $(y^2 + 2y + 1)$ so that it's $(y^2 + y + 1)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please look up the [styling guide for MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question a bit.

Comment: :-( Why is there a daily limit on comment upvotes so that I cannot upvote your amazing comment? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: In your second line of algebra, the division symbol should instead be a multiplication symbol.

Comment: @SimpleArt I'm not sure. I've always wondered why that cap exists, especially for 10K+ rep users. I wouldn't call my comment "amazing" by any means XD

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen But we need it lol.  And if I didn't have a rep cap... >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $\dfrac{\dfrac{y^{3}-1}{y^{2}-1}}{\dfrac{y^{2}+y+1}{y^{2}+2y+1}}$

You were correct in stating that we "flip the fraction", but you incorrectly displayed a division symbol rather than a multiplication symbol.

The author never got rid of the $2y$; the expression $y^{2}+2y+1$ was factored into $(y+1)(y+1)$.

$=\dfrac{y^{3}-1}{y^{2}-1}\times\dfrac{y^{2}+2y+1}{y^{2}+y+1}$

$=\dfrac{(y-1)(y^{2}+y+1)}{(y+1)(y-1)}\cdot\dfrac{(y+1)(y+1)}{(y^{2}+y+1)}$

$=y+1$

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know how they factored out the "2"? The numerator factors out to: (y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + y + 1)  but how did they get rid of the "2"???

Comment: would you mind looking over an image of how the author solves the problem step by step if i uploaded one?

Comment: The author did not get rid of the $2y$. I believe that your confusion may be a result of the author not showing a step or two of the working out.

Comment: You made a mistake on factoring $y^3-1$.

Comment: okay thank you i understand what you were saying now. someone else pointed out that i didn't factor it out right either

Answer (score 3):

The $y^2+2y+1$ is still there as $(y+1)(y+1)$.  The factor $y^2+y+1$ is from the denominator of the last fraction, which, after inverting and multiplying, is on top.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be more specific? Once you flip it to multiply in the numerator we have: (y^3 - 1)(y^2 + 2y + 1), but once you factor we have (y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + y + 1), I understand that "(y - 1)(y + 1)(y + 1)" came from "(y^3 - 1)" **but** how did "(y^2 + 2y + 1)" become "(y^2 + y + 1)"??

Comment: @Larvitar $y^3-1=(y-1)(y^2+y+1)$ and $y^2+2y+1=(y+1)(y+1)$

Comment: thank you, now i understand

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the factorisation of $y^3-1$ and $y^2+2y+1$:
$$\dfrac{y^{3}-1}{y^{2}-1}\times\dfrac{y^{2}+2y+1}{y^{2}+y+1}=\frac{( y-1)(y^2+y+1)}{(y-1)(y+1)}\times\frac{(y+1)^2}{y^2+y+1}=y+1.$$

Comment: thank you for your explanation, someone else gave me the correct answer first but plz keep this answer up there as i'm sure it will help someone else out. and for future reference: y^3 - 1 factors to: (y - 1)(y^2 + y + 1), and y^2 + 2y + 1 factors out to: (y + 1)(y + 1). i think the problem with me (And maybe some other people) is that we **see** the steps but there's no explanation behind it. like I NEVER would of gotten it if "kingW3" hadn't explained it the way he did. I'm not saying your way of doing it is wrong just that **i** didn't get it. anyways yeah thank you very much

Comment: In general, I only recall the fundamental identities everyone should know. I think it's  a better intellectual stimulation to not give all the details, but only a sketch – sweating on a problem before having explanations is more fruitful in the long time, from my point of view. Of course, in a second step, I can add details if asked for

Answer (score 2):

$(y^3-1)/(y^2-1) ÷ (y^2 + y + 1)/(y^2 + 2y + 1)=$

$(y^3-1)/(y^2-1)\times (y^2 +2 y + 1)/(y^2 + y + 1)=$

$\frac {(y^3 -1)(y^2+2y+1)}{(y^2-1)(y^2+y+1)}=M$

I think you've followed and figured all that on your own.

Now comes.... experience, intuition and elbow grease.

Does $y^3 - 1$ factor?  I know it does because I've been doing this stuff for 35 years.  If it does then it will be of the form $(ay^2 + by + c)(dy + e)$ where $ad = 1$ and $ce = -1$ and ... some mess of inside stuff will cancel out.  (Actually $ady^3 + (bd + ea)y^2 + (be+ cd)y + ec = x^3 - 1$ so $ad = 1; bd+ea = 0; be+cd=0; ec=-1$).

First guess is $e =\pm 1; c= \mp1; a = 1;d = 1$ and we get $(y^2 + by \mp 1)(y \pm 1) = y^3 + by^2 \mp y \pm y^2 \pm by - 1= y^3 +(b \pm 1)y^2 + (\pm b \mp 1)y  -1 = y^3 - 1$ so $b \pm 1 = 0$ and $b - 1 = 0$ so $b = 1$ and $y^3 - 1 = (y-1)(y^2 + y + 1)$.

Indeed, we should probably learn and put it in a arsenel of tricks that $(x-1)(x^n + x^{n-1} + ...... + x + 1) = x^{n+1} + (1-1)x^{n-1} + ..... + (1-1)x -1 = x^{n+1} - 1$ is a good bit of factoring that we will use a lot in the future.

So $y^3 - 1 = (y-1)(y^2 + y+ 1)$ and we have:

$M =\frac{(y^3 - 1)(y^2+2y+1)}{(y^2 - 1)(y^2+ y + 1)} = \frac{(y-1)(y^2+y+1)(y^2 + 2y + 1)}{(y^2- 1)(y^2 + y+1)} = \frac{(y-1)(y^2 + 2y + 1)}{y^2 - 1}$

Now does $y^2 - 1$ factor.  Well, above we say $(x-1)(x^n + .... + 1) = x^{n+1} -1$ so $y^2 - 1 = (y-1)(y+1)$.  We can check that: $(y-1)(y+1) = y^2 - y + y - 1 = y^2-1$.

So

$M = \frac{(y-1)(y^2 + 2y + 1)}{y^2 - 1}=$

$\frac{(y-1)(y^2 + 2y + 1)}{(y-1)(y+1)} =\frac{(y^2 + 2y + 1)}{(y+1)}$

Now the question is: does $y^2 + 2y + 1$ factor?  Well, yes... $y^2 + 2y + 1 = (y+1)^2$

So $M = \frac{y^2 + 2y + 1}{y+1} = \frac{(y+1)^2}{y+1} = y+1$. and.... we are done.